# Techniques for converting OO C++ to Java (No conversion tools)

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have looked around, and there are no solid guidelines to converting Object Orientated C++ to Java. Most are references to conversion tools.

My question is what are the steps one should take to not get overwhelmed and lost, especially for heavily OO projects.

For example, given one method that accomplishes a task. That method is called, which is dependent on several other cpp, and those helper methods are also dependent on other cpp files, and so on. How should this be addressed?

What are techniques that can be used to break it down, while properly combining .hpp and .cpp?

I understand JNI can be used, however, it is desired to have only Java code, unless something can literally only be done in C++

Tips, suggestions, and ideas will be much appreciated.

PLEASE do NOT mark this as a DUPLICATE, there are only questions posted in respect to specific code, or using conversion tools, not for general techniques.

Also, if this is a terrible question, let me know, I'll take it down, no need to thumb it down. Thank you.

Comment: This question is far too broad.

Comment: I think that your question could be improved by including a concrete sample of the code you have concerns about, so that we have something concrete to base answers off, and the question is narrowed to something that isn't too broad for SO.

Comment: seems like a pretty bad idea to try to do this for a large project without conversion tools. why do you want to do this without tools?

Comment: Ok, I can add some concrete examples. Just for other questions, where people do that, it tends to have a negative response. I'll work on the examples now.

Comment: @nhouser9 it seems like a pretty bad idea to do *with* tools to me. I could easily imagine ending up with a huge pile of non-idiomatic, inefficient Java that is a far bigger maintenance burden than you'd get from sitting down and writing it again properly in Java. Also, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3qjs1w/are_there_good_c_to_java_code_converters/).

Comment: The use of conversion tools is not forbidden. It appears it would be difficult to use tools, but that is an assumption. How do they address complicated header and cpp files? Do they combine them?

Comment: Also, like @AndyTurner said, I was worried about having spaghetti code after the conversion.  Making it difficult to modify and understand.